# Is it possible to extend the User.Identity structure (ASP.Net/MVC) somehow?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to store additional data specific to the currently logged on user somehow?

Comment: what were you thinking of storing?

Comment: User's full name and a reference to an image file.

Comment: Where do you intend to store those additional values?

Comment: Ideally, in the same location as the current values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly! If you are not familiar with writing an extension, there are the [VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) and [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) guides on the subject.

You will need to extend the `System.Security.Principal.IIdentity` interface. As an example:

**Declaration:**

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module Extensions

    <Extension()>
    Function GetMyCustomProperty(anIdentity As System.Security.Principal.IIdentity, myParameter As Integer) As Object

        Return New Object()

    End Function

End Module
```

**Usage:**

```
User.Identity.GetMyCustomProperty(4)
```

**NOTES:**

- The C# code is a fair deal different so it's worth looking at the
  guides on how extensions are implemented in general. Running this
  code through a VB.NET => C# converter is not enough.
- Extensions may only be methods. You may not program custom properties. This will likely mean implementing getter/setter methods if you want property-like behavior.

**EDIT:**

After seeing your comments, I assume you are doing this to provide a sort of crude functionality similar to a user profile. Consider using a profile provider in concert with any membership you are currently using if you'd like this functionality.

Comment: If extensions do not allow custom properties, how do they store custom state relevant to themselves?

Comment: They do not. Extensions are inherently function more like static methods so that means you'd need to either access the state information of the object they extend, move state data to a backing store (such as a database), or utilize the current user's session bag through `HttpContext.Current.Session`. If you are looking to implement a user profile, you would do better to utilize a profile provider.